# How to move MVC application from one server to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Currently we are subscribed to GoDaddy for their dedicated server lease, and now we are considering just purchasing our own server and just moving off of GoDaddy.

I have no idea how to put all of my source code from one server to another and also move the database and other files. Please explain what process has to be followed for this.

Also wanted to ask if their would be any changed for the third party tools i have used in my application?

Comment: So do you want to publish your MVC app on IIS?

Comment: yes @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Then publish the project to a local folder --> Then copy all published output and paste inside your IIS folder directoty

Comment: @PrashantPimpale is that all i have to do for hosting my application to a new server? what about database and third party apps, nothing special to be done for them?

Comment: @SJ lee Yes, all you need is database server SqlServer which allow you to connect to it and access database and IIS server which is configured to access over the internet.

Comment: Can you explain all related information about what you have like IIS, SQL Server?

Comment: 3rd party APIs like FedEx, UPS, USPS, PayPal, Web and Window Services. Amazon S3, Email, Printer related App and hardware etc.

i have no idea if all these things will be affected after i port my application to the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate my web application from one server to another I would do following :

1. Make a list of all transferable which would be:

   - Latest and running Source code on the server (ideally located in wwwroot)
   - database back up files (usually .mdb or .bak)
2. Copy source code and database back up to targeted server. Obviously depending upon type of the server you may need to set up the site in IIS and and point it to new directory
3. Restore database backup on database server
4. edit web.config to point to new database server and credentials.

**Another important tip: If you have kept domain name with GoDaddy and only changing hosting server you may also need to change namedserver of you domain, without which you will not be able to point your domain to new hosting provider!**

You may not succeed on the very first attempt of copying your stuffs to target server. It's always better to maintain back up so that you can copy files again and again in case something goes wrong on the new server.

As long as third party charges are concerned please check with your service providers they may be able to guide you best. For above simple stuff you do not need to worry about license stuff.

All the best!